# Yet another date formatting problem :(

Tags: vb.net, datetime, formatting

I seem to have a date formatting problem every day!

I am querying a table and am getting a date back in the format dd/mm/yyyy (as a string btw). Brilliant! thats what I want. But, now I want to convert that string to a date so i can do

```
dim dayNumber as integer = day.DayOfWeek
```

But when I convert it to a date it changes it to #m/dd/yyyy#. AHHHH! how can I change this?

here is my code i've tried

```
Dim ActivityDate As String
If dt.Rows(i)("Date") Is DBNull.Value Then
    ActivityDate = ""
Else
    ActivityDate = dt.Rows(i)("Date")
End If

Dim ci As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA")
Dim theDate As Date = Date.Parse(ActivityDate, ci)

Dim day As Integer = theDate.DayOfWeek
```

Cheers

Comment: Why are you pulling a string date from the database?  _This should be a datetime column,_ and that means you can assign non-null values to a datetime variable directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Brilliant! thats what I want

That's not what you want.  It is the worst possible format for a date because it is so horribly ambiguous.  Date string formats depend on the current culture.  "4/1/2010" is Unicorn day at SO, it is day in January in Europe.  "#4/1/2010#" is a legacy VB6 format.

*Always* store dates in a DateTime in your code.  *Always* store dates in a database column type of datetime in your dbase.  There is never any ambiguity and you'll have an easy time with the DateTime members to manipulate dates.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the string to a date, you can always output it back to the original format using a custom format string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: I've tried a few of the example from the link but none have formatted it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution here (at least until you tell us why this isn't possible) is to update your database to use a datetime column type rather than a varchar.  Now we also know that this column has no NULL values, because otherwise you'd be complaining about exceptions on your `Date.Parse()` call.  After applying both those sentences, you can trim all that code down to a simple one-liner:

```
Dim day As Integer = DirectCast(dt.Rows(i)("Date"), DateTime).DayOfWeek
```

May I also ask why you're looping through the table row by row?  I've worked in a shop where that was the norm, but since I've left there I've run in to alternatives and more and more I'm coming to find looping through a datatable as just wrong.  It's an older imperative coding style, and generally you want to go for a declarative coding style.

Answer (score 0):

Are you parsing it like this:

```
Dim newDate as DateTime = DateTime.Parse(myDate)
```

Comment: I wasn't no. Tried that and it was just the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the culture of your system does not use that date format, then you should get that date string as an actual date:

```
' canadian date format is dd/mm/yyyy 
Dim ci As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA")
Dim theDate As Date = Date.Parse("13/04/2010", ci)
```

Comment: I've retrieved the date as string. So will be converting from string to date. I tried your example but it never changed the formatting  :(

I've added the code to my post

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify an exact parse format like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("17/12/2010", "dd/mm/yyyy", null));
```

I am not sure  what the last parameter is but it is safe to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are seeing the #m/dd/yyyy# in the debugger, like this screenshot below. Don't worry!

A `Date` variable isn't stored as a string. The debugger has to convert your `Date` into a string to display it, and it **insists** on showing dates in #m/dd/yyyy# format. But that doesn't have any effect on the runtime behaviour of your program.

[Screenshot of Visual Studio Debugger http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6205/debugger.gif](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6205/debugger.gif)